# Matching rows between two dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have managed to write this piece of code but as I am using it on big data sets it ends up being quite slow. I am pretty sure it would be possible to optimize it but I am very knew to coding and I don't really know where to start.. I think getting rid of the for loop would be one way but honestly I'm lost. A little bit of help would be greatly appreciated !

Basically, the point is to look if one row of the 'data' dataframe match one row of the 'ref' dataframe. And I use np.isclose in order to allow for small differences in the value as I know my 'data' values can be slightly different than the 'ref' values.

Also, because my rows can have a lot of NaN values in them, I first use np.isnan to get the index of where is my last 'real' value in the row and then only do the row comparison with the 'actual' values. I thought it would speed things up but I'm not very sure it did...

```
match = []
checklist = set()

for read in data.itertuples():

    for ref in ref.itertuples():

        x = np.isnan(read[3:]).argmax(axis=0)

        if x == 2:
            if np.isclose(read[4:6],ref[7:9],atol=5, equal_nan=True).all() == True and np.isnan(ref[6:]).argmax(axis=0) == x:


                if not read[1] in checklist:
                    match.append([read[1], ref[5]])
                    checklist.add(read[1])

        if x > 2:
            read_pos = 3+x-1
            ref_pos = 6+x-1

            if np.isclose(read[4:read_pos],ref[7:ref_pos],atol=5, equal_nan=True).all() == True and np.isnan(ref[6:]).argmax(axis=0) == x:


                if not read[1] in checklist:
                    match.append([read[1], ref[5]])
                    checklist.add(read[1])

    if read[1] not in checklist:
        match.append([read[1], "not found"])
        checklist.add(read[1])
```

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**

To download samples of data and ref tables: https://we.tl/RF6lxDZBjt

Short example of the dataframes:

```
ref = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a-1','a-2','b-1'],
                  'start 1':[100,100,100],
                  'end 1':[200,200,500],
                  'start 2':[300,np.NaN,600],
                  'end 2':[400,np.NaN, 700]}, 
                   columns=['name', 'start 1', 'end 1', 'start 2', 'end 2'], 
                   dtype='float64')


    name  start 1   end 1  start 2  end 2
 0  a-1     100.0   200.0    300.0  400.0
 1  a-2     100.0   200.0      NaN    NaN
 2  b-1     100.0   500.0    600.0  700.0




data = pd.DataFrame({'name':['read 1','read 2','read 3','read 4', 'read 5'],
                  'start 1':[100,102,100,103,600],
                  'end 1':[198,504,500,200, 702],
                  'start 2':[np.NaN,600,650,601, np.NaN],
                  'end 2':[np.NaN,699, 700,702, np.NaN]}, 
                   columns=['name', 'start 1', 'end 1', 'start 2', 'end 2'], 
                   dtype='float64')


    read      start 1   end 1  start 2   end 2
 0  read 1      100.0   200.0    300.0   400.0
 1  read 2      100.0   200.0      NaN     NaN
 2  read 3      100.0   500.0    600.0   700.0
 3  read 4      300.0   400.0    600.0   700.0
 4  read 5      600.0   702.0      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: @Graipher Did you happen to have time to look at it ? If not, I totally understand ! If you even have a small idea of things that I could try I'm willing to try it myself ! I tried looking into vectorization but I really don't know where to start.. Thanks anyway for your time, it's greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not yet, but I will have some time tomorrow. Yes, writing good (in other words vectorised) code in numpy/pandas is a whole new world if you only know vanilla Python.

Comment: Would you think it's possible to remove the outer for loop by using apply instead ? and put the vectorization of the inner loop in a function ?

Answer (score 2):

Invariants

```
for read in data.itertuples():
    for ref in ref.itertuples():
        x = np.isnan(read[3:]).argmax(axis=0)
```

`x` doesn't change in the inner loop, so you can move it out of the inner loop, and not execute it repeatedly.

```
for read in data.itertuples():
    x = np.isnan(read[3:]).argmax(axis=0)
    for ref in ref.itertuples():
```

These following two lines are identical, apart for the end-points of the slices:

```
if np.isclose(read[4:  6     ],ref[7:  9    ],atol=5, equal_nan=True).all() == True and np.isnan(ref[6:]).argmax(axis=0) == x:
if np.isclose(read[4:read_pos],ref[7:ref_pos],atol=5, equal_nan=True).all() == True and np.isnan(ref[6:]).argmax(axis=0) == x:
```

You already have a variable for the end-points.  Why not use it for the first line as well, and only have one case?

```
read_pos = 3+x-1 if x > 2 else 6
ref_pos  = 6+x-1 if x > 2 else 9
```

Once you've found your target, you can't ever add it again ...

```
if not read[1] in checklist:
   match.append([read[1], ref[5]])
   checklist.add(read[1])
```

... but you don't `break` out of your inner search, which is now pointless.

---

If I haven't made any errors, this should be a litte faster:

```
match = []
checklist = set()

for read in data.itertuples():

    x = np.isnan(read[3:]).argmax(axis=0)

    if x >= 2  and  read[1] not in checklist:

        read_pos = 3+x-1 if x > 2 else 6
        ref_pos  = 6+x-1 if x > 2 else 9

        for ref in ref.itertuples():

            if np.isclose(read[4:read_pos],ref[7:ref_pos],atol=5, equal_nan=True).all() == True and np.isnan(ref[6:]).argmax(axis=0) == x:
                match.append([read[1], ref[5]])
                checklist.add(read[1])
                break

    if read[1] not in checklist:
        match.append([read[1], "not found"])
        checklist.add(read[1])
```

Comment: Thanks ! It didn't improve the speed that much but at least it made realize some mistakes I did and it is much more easy to read and understand so that's already a nice improvement !